# Rearrange array data and seperate in new array php

Tags: php, arrays

**Array a**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 6
            [sorting] => 0
            [total] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 7
            [sorting] => 1
            [total] => 2
        )

)
```

**Array b**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 2
            [total] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 6
            [total] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 7
            [total] => 2
        )

)
```

**Question:** Above data I try to loop the array and store into new array like the below **(Final data)**. First of all, if the second array is missing the member data, then I need to get from the first array and store it into a new array. Besides that, I need to get the sorting value from the first array if the sorting is missing. In the end, I able to get all the data nicely but the last value store into it will duplicate. Anyone can help on this :(? My logic stuck at here.

***My code return***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 6
            [total] => 1
            [sorting] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 7
            [total] => 2
            [sorting] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 7
            [total] => 2
            [sorting] => 
        )

)
```

**Final data should be:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 6
            [total] => 1
            [sorting] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 7
            [total] => 2
            [sorting] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => 2
            [total] => 3
            [sorting] => 2
        )

)
```

code : https://3v4l.org/WBLCC

Comment: How did you get `sorting` as `2` for member_id `2`?

Comment: The sorting will based on the current data in the array and then +1.

Comment: Means? First get all common elements and then do a +1 for sorting for every non element found?

Comment: ya correct.....

Comment: because i stuck in the member id, the last member id should be 2 instead of 7. Seem like duplicate

Comment: Your existing elements in the input array have `sorting` values of `0` and `1`. Will that always be like that - starting with 0, and consecutive? Or can the start value be different, can there be “holes” in the already existing sorting values? What if you have more than one element in $b, that has no sorting entry in $a? Do you want those to be inserted / sorted into the existing ones in their original order?

Comment: Ya, it will store/inserted sorted into the existing ones in their original order.

Comment: @CBroe, the array A sorting it will be consecutive.

Comment: @alanlm Can you add some more input-output examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// create a version of $a that uses the member_id as key, makes look-up easier
$a_reindexed = array_combine( array_column($a, 'member_id'), array_values($a) );
// get the current maximum sorting value from the elements in $a
$max_sort = max(array_column($a, 'sorting'));

$result = [];
// add values from $b to the result
foreach($b as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
    // set the sorting property to that of the corresponding element from $a_reindexed
    // or PHP_INT_MAX if the former doesn’t exist
    $result[$key]['sorting'] = $a_reindexed[$value['member_id']]['sorting'] ?? PHP_INT_MAX;
}
// sort the result array by the sorting value, so all elements with PHP_INT_MAX will go to the end
usort($result, function($a, $b) { return $a['sorting'] <=> $b['sorting']; });
// set new sorting value for all items having it set to PHP_INT_MAX
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
  if($value['sorting'] == PHP_INT_MAX) {
    $result[$key]['sorting'] = ++$max_sort;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic solution that might suit your needs:

```
/*
 * first, store all records with matching member_id into store $c
 */
$c = [];
foreach ($b as $key0 => $value0) {
    foreach ($a as $key1 => $value1) {
        // matching 'member_id'?
        if ($value0['member_id'] === $value1['member_id']) {
            // inject record into store $c
            $c[] = $a[$key1];
        }
    }
}

/*
 * second, inject non-matching records from $b into store $c
 */
$ids = array_column($c, 'member_id');
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['member_id'], $ids)) {
        $sorting = max(array_column($c, 'sorting')) + 1;
        $value['sorting'] = $sorting;
        $c[] = $value;
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/GkSGn)